# Как подружить urlManager в конфиге c urlManager модуля в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как подружить `urlManager` с правилами в конфиге:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/index',
                '/admin' => 'admin/default/index',
                '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',
            ],
        ],
```

с правилами описанными в модуле (в данном случае приведен модуль Yii2-user)

```
/** @var array The rules to be used in URL management. */
    public $urlRules = [
        '<id:\d+>'                    => 'profile/show',
        '<action:(login|logout)>'     => 'security/<action>',
        '<action:(register|resend)>'  => 'registration/<action>',
        'confirm/<id:\d+>/<code:\w+>' => 'registration/confirm',
        'forgot'                      => 'recovery/request',
        'recover/<id:\d+>/<code:\w+>' => 'recovery/reset',
        'settings/<action:\w+>'       => 'settings/<action>'
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите тут: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#adding-rules

перевод:

> URL правила могут быть добавлены в URL менеджер динамически. Это часто
>   необходимо для распространяемых модулей, которые хотят самостоятельно
>   управлять своими URl правилами. Для того чтобы динамически добавленные
>   правила вступили в силу в процессе маршрутизации, вы должны добавить
>   их на стадии Самонастройки (bootstrapping). Для модулей это означает,
>   что они должны реализовывать yii\base\BootstrapInterface и добавлять
>   правила в bootstrap() метод как в примере:

```
public function bootstrap($app)
{
    $app->getUrlManager()->addRules([
        // rule declarations here
    ], false);
}
```

> Заметьте, что вы должны также указать эти модули в
>   yii\web\Application::bootstrap() что бы они участвовали в процесссе
>   самонастройки